# Django Admin and Forms. BaseInlineFormSet. def clean( )

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I need to implement a prohibition on removing the last ingredient from a recipe. So that the recipe is not left empty without ingredients, or make the recipe deleted when the last ingredient is deleted. I need to use BaseInlineFormset and method def clean( ), but i dont understand this

```
class RecipeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name',
                    'author',
                    )
    list_filter = ('name', 'author',
                   ('tags', admin.RelatedOnlyFieldListFilter),)
    inlines = (IngredientRecipeInline, TagRecipeInline)

class IngredientRecipeInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = IngredientRecipe
    min_num = 1
```

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=200
    )
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        related_name='recipes',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
    )
    text = models.TextField(
    )
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(
        Ingredient,
        related_name='recipes',
        through='IngredientRecipe'
    )
```

I"ve tried this but dont work

```
class FormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):
    def clean(self):
        super(FormSet, self).clean()

        for form in self.forms:
            if not hasattr(form, 'cleaned_data'):
                continue

            data = form.cleaned_data

            if (data.get('DELETE') and form.instance.ingredients == 1):
                raise ValidationError('You cannot delete')
```